# convert SQL full outer join of the same table to Full outer join of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can i convert following SQl that do full outer join on a table

```
FROM df AS df1 FULL OUTER JOIN df AS df2
ON df1.date = df2.date AND df1.product != df2.product
```

does

```
     pd.merge(df1,df2, on="date , how="outer")
```

do the same? i guess not then how can i also tell pandas `df1.product != df2.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's very hard to do non-equality join predicates in pandas. You'll have to first do your merge, then, assuming the result is stored in variable `t`, filter you products: `t[t['product_x'] != t['product_y']]`.

There are some packages (pandasql, duckdb) that let you query directly on dataframes, so that you can apply complex predicates, but I heard it can be rather slow. If your dataframe is of an intermediate size (fits comfortably in memory) I guess the first option is the simplest.